# How can I call a method outside the executing assembly in MSIL?

Tags: c#, hook, clr, jit, cil

I have access to a function body Intermediate Language like this :

```cs
byte[] ilCodes = NestedFooInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
```

I am able to modify its IL code so that before executing the method body I call the following method named `OnChangeField`:

```cs
public static void OnChangeField()
{
    Console.WriteLine("VICTORY");
    return;
}
```

So far I do it like this :

I define the call instruction to the method I want to call:

```cs
MethodInfo OnStfld = typeof(MethodBoundaryAspect).GetMethod("OnChangeField");
byte[] callIL = new byte[5];
callIL[0] = (byte)OpCodes.Call.Value;
callIL[1] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken & 0xFF);
callIL[2] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 8 & 0xFF);
callIL[3] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 16 & 0xFF);
callIL[4] = (byte)(OnStfld.MetadataToken >> 24 & 0xFF);
```

Notice that OnChangeField is located in the MethodBoundaryAspect Class. This class is located outside the assembly of the method beeing edited.

And this is how I alter the original(`NestedFoo(...)`) method body :

```cs
byte[] ilCodes = NestedFooInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray();
InjectionHelper.UpdateILCodes(NestedFooInfo, callIL.Concat(ilCodes).ToArray());
```

And I get a :

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)'

But *only*  if the hooking method `OnChangeField` is outside (or so I understood) the executing assemly. If I move `OnChangeField` in the same class as NestedFoo or in another class of `NestedFoo`'s assembly, it works perfectly.

I understand that the metadatatoken points towards a memory location which isn't valid. Is there a way to change that ?

For references here is :
what the method body of the altered method looks like:

```cs
public class ExceptionHandlingService : IExceptionHandlingService
{
        public static string var1 = "initialValue";
        public static string Var2 { get; set; } = "initialValue";
        public string var3 = "initialValue";
        public string Var4 { get; set; } = "initialValue";

        public string NestedFoo(SampleClass bar)
        {
            var1 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            Var2 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            var3 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            Var4 = "value set in NestedFoo()";
            AddPerson("From", "NestedFoo", 2);
            return Foo();
        }
        [...]
}
```

and how I call the altered method :

```cs
var a = new ExceptionHandlingService();
var b = new SampleClass("bonjour", 2, 3L); // Not really relevant
a.NestedFoo(b);
```

For those who wonder what magic happens in
`InjectionHelper.UpdateILCodes(NestedFooInfo, newIlCodes);` you can check [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time) which shows how you can edit Il code at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add records to `MemberRef` and consecutively `TypeRef` or `TypeSpec` metadata tables to contain references to types and reference these tokens. This also involves properly writing signature blobs.

See Partition II 22.38, 22.25 of [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)